# How can I get/access the 'name' attribute from the user data dictionary in twitter in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, twitter, twython

I've downloaded some tweets with Twython.
I want to get/access only the 'name' attribute from the 'user' object dictionary (e.g. {'id': 540179903, 'id_str': '540179903', 'name': 'Makis Voridis' etc.
How could I solve this??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a dictionary, you can simply acess each key by simply doing `tweet['name']` and tweet being your dictionary.

Comment: The correct answer was tweet['name']['user']. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted and close this post if you solved the issue!